# Symfony cmd error "The target-entity..cannot be found in.."

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm starting with Symfony Framework and I am trying to make ManyToMany relationship.
But when I try this commandline

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update
```

I am getting this error:

```
The target-entity C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-tp\src\Entity\Competetence cannot be found in 'App\Entity\Stagiaire#competencies'.
```

**Stagiaire.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\StagiaireRepository")
 */
class Stagiaire
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-tp\src\Entity\Competetence",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $competencies;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $birthday;
    /**
     * @var \Datetime
     */
    private $date;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \Datetime();
        $this->competencies = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addCompetence(Competence $competence)
    {
        $this->$competence[] = $competence;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCompetence(Competence $competence)
    {
        $this->competencies->removeElement($competence);
    }

    public function getCompetencies()
    {
        return $this->competencies;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?int
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(int $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthday(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthday;
    }

    public function setBirthday(\DateTimeInterface $birthday): self
    {
        $this->birthday = $birthday;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Competence.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CompetenceRepository")
 */
class Competence
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Stagiaire::$competencies` annotation you need to provide `Competence`'s Fully-Qualified Class Name instead of file path on your computer, and that would be `App\Entity\Competence`

So this:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-tp\src\Entity\Competetence",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $competencies;
```

Becomes:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Competence",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $competencies;
```